# Linux mint - classify an application correctly in the start menu

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, programming, eclipse

Mint auto-classifies applications into categories in the start menu. I use this classification to navigate apps more easily.
Recently I have installed Eclipse IDE and Mint failed to classify it as "programming", instead labeling it as "other".  How do I manually classify this application as "programming"?

Answer (score 1):

One way, using a GUI tool, you can use `menulibre`. It's available in the official repos.

[image: menulibre]